# In a three bar linkage, find the angle between the first link and line connecting the end point to origin

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Consider the three bar linkage $OABC$ below, where $OA = L_1$, $AB = L_2$ and $BC = L_3$, and  $L_1 \ne L_2 \ne L_3$. Given the lengths $L_n$ and point $C$ $(x,y)$, what is the angle $\theta$ between OA and OC?

[image]

Assume the following:

- The given point is always reachable, i.e. $\sqrt{x_c^2 + y_c^2} < L_1 + L_2 + L_3)$
- $L_2$ is the longest link and always crosses $OC$

This one has me stumped. I don't have enough information to use sine or cosine law, but clearly there is a solution since the revolute joints at A and B allow the linkage to fit. How can I solve this?

Comment: There are, in general, infinite solutions to this problem.

Comment: Draw a circle of radius $L_1$ around $O$ and one of radius $L_3$ around $C$. Your problem reduces to finding points $A$ and $B$ on these respective circles such that $AB=L_2$ and $\overline{AB}$ crosses $\overline{OC}$.